# How to write subquery in From clause in django ORM

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I wnat to write this query using django orm

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary, enroll_date
FROM
  (SELECT depname, empno, salary, enroll_date,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC) AS pos
     FROM empsalary
  ) AS ss
WHERE pos < 3;
```

My current ORm query

```
EmpSalary.objects.values('depname', 'empno', 'salary', 'enroll_date').annotate(
pos= Window(
                expression=RowNumber(),
                partition_by=[F('depname')],
                order_by=F('salary').desc(),
            )
)
```

The above ORM queryset roughly translates to the inner query

```
SELECT depname, empno, salary, enroll_date,
          rank() OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC) AS pos
     FROM empsalary
```

I want to know how i can get the whole inner query in the FROM clause of the outer query.

Comment: Don't you just need to add `.filter(pos__lt=3)`?

Comment: it dosent work ... gives an exception windows expresions are not filterable.

Comment: Please check this https://pypi.org/project/django-sub-query/

Comment: Did you find a solution that does not include a third-party package?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it's not possible to use a `Window` query inside a `WHERE` clause. So instead, use a `Subquery`:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

top_salaries = EmpSalary.objects.filter(
    depname=OuterRef('depname')
).order_by('-salary')[:3]
result = EmpSalary.objects.filter(
    pk__in=Subquery(top_salaries.values('pk'))
).values('depname', 'empno', 'salary', 'enroll_date')
```

Comment: it dosent work. The Subquery is put in the WHERE clause of the Outer Query. Is there a way  by which the SUBQUERY goes into the FROM clause ?