# Is a subquery of this kind possible in django?

Tags: django

In sql I can do something like this -

```
select a, b, c from (
  select a, b, c from table_a
)
where a = something
```

Is this possible with django?  I've only ever used subquery of the type where the primary key of the subquery for example maps to a column of a row in the parent query.  I don't want this though on this occasion.

Here is the context.

I have a query which has an annotated column which uses a Window frame.  Such an expression cannot be included in a WHERE clause because sql evaluates the where clause first.  So it is necessary to perform this query first as a subquery and then use the result like it is its own table.  On this parent query I can then filter.

See - https://learnsql.com/blog/window-functions-not-allowed-in-where/

```
class Item(models.Model):
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

# you asked for it!
def get_whens(category_ordering, page_size):
    page_number = Ceil(Cast(F('row_number') * 1.0 /
                            page_size, output_field=FloatField()))

    return [
        When(
            category__name=c,
            then=(
                Cast(
                    (page_number * len(category_ordering) - len(category_ordering) +
                     category_ordering.index(c) + 1)  # real_page_number
                    *
                    page_size
                    -
                    page_size
                    +
                    F('row_number')
                    -
                    (
                        (page_number - 1)
                        *
                        page_size
                    ),
                    output_field=IntegerField()
                )
            )
        )
        for c in category_ordering
    ]



q = (
        Item
        .objects
        .annotate(
            row_number=Window(
                expression=RowNumber(),
                partition_by=[F('category_id')]
            )
        )
        .annotate(
            order_value=Case(*get_whens(category_ordering, page_size))
        )
        .order_by('order_value')
)
```

**Latest**

I don't think this is possible.  Found a similar question - [How to write subquery in From clause in django ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864345/how-to-write-subquery-in-from-clause-in-django-orm)

I'll have to write a raw sql query instead.

I have added a comment to this ticket - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333#comment:17

Comment: Django supports [explicit subqueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). Could you provide the current query and model(s)?

Comment: Yes that's the subquery kind I'm aware of.  The example they provide though in the docs is different to this situation.

Comment: Is it the `row_number` annotation that you want to filter on?

Comment: No I'll need to filter on the order_value column.  This column depends on the row_number column.  The callable get_whens involves logic which is irrelevant but involves the row_number column, you see.

Comment: Can you share `get_whens`? How the window annotation is used may change the solution

Answer (score 0):

I've added a comment to this ticket so we can solve this kind of problem through django's ORM - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333#comment:17.

For now I've solved the problem with this third party package - https://github.com/dimagi/django-cte.  It offers common table expressions through the django orm.

My solution is based on the basic example the package gives.

```
    q = (
        Item
        .objects
        .annotate(
            row_number=Window(
                expression=RowNumber(),
                partition_by=[F('category_id')]
            )
        )
        .annotate(
            order_value=Case(*get_whens(category_ordering, page_size))
        )
        .order_by('order_value')
    )
    cte = With(q)
    actual_queryset = (
        cte
        .join(Item, pk=cte.col.pk)
        .with_cte(cte)
        .annotate(order_value=cte.col.order_value)
        .order_by('order_value')
    )
```